# Observe SQLite user_version changes

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible somehow to observe changes in the SQLite database user_version pragma, aside from constantly pooling it?

My use case is: I have an application which uses SQLite database as an app file format. Since multiple people can use the same database simultaneously, I need to know right away if a database file format version was changed and reload the database.

For tables, I can use data change notification callbacks, but they do not work for pragma values. I suspect that I have to start using user_version table instead, but there is a slight chance that somebody can come up with a solution working with pragma..

Comment: SQLite has no mechanism for multiple processes to communicate with each other.

Comment: I was not aware of that. The documentation does not specify it, but it is documented in the source code..